Ubuntu 22.04, Eclipse version 2024-09, when search, the search screen becomes a white area
Ubuntu 22.04, Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)  Version: 2024-09 (4.33.0), when I press ctrl+F, the search screen show and allow to input the search text, but it change to a white area quickly.
I don't know if this question should ask in Ubuntu or Eclipse forum.
screen is attached:
when press ctrl-F,

but then change to a white area rapidly

